# как считать getlin-ом с файла с++

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream

задача проста, но не могу разобраться, мне нужно построчно считывать из файла.

```
    bkkk book;
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
  ifstream lib("lib.txt");
  int n;
  lib>>n;
  cout << n<< endl;
   //
  lib.getline(book.name, 50);
    cout << book.name<<endl;
    //
  lib.getline(book.autor, 50);
    cout << book.autor<<endl;
    //
  lib >>book.artcl;
    cout << book.artcl<<endl;
    //
  lib >>book.cond;
    cout << book.cond<<endl;
    //
  lib >>book.reit;
    cout << book.reit<<endl;
    //
```

выводит :

```
2

Эти свободные бабочки
0
-922093277
0
```

вместо :

```
2
Эти свободные бабочки
Герш
45788
1
5,5
```

как я понял, проблема в том, что `lib>>`- не переводи на след строку. как это можно исправить?

Comment: Если у вас Windows, то перевод строки в файле нужно заменить с `\n\r` на `\n`, либо задать его третьм параметром `getline`

Comment: @free_ze, зачем? Си же сам разгребает форматы переводов строк в текстовом режиме.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, вероятнее всего вы правы, это же стандартная библиотека, которая обязана быть переносимой.

Answer (score 4):

После чтения типа

```
lib >>book.cond;
```

в буфере остается остаток строки (как минимум `\n`). Убрать его можно (и нужно), вызывая после этого чтения сброс символов до конца строки, например:

```
lib.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```